# Which analyses are most appropriate for answering the following questions about within-subjects data (with missing data)?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, missing-data, multilevel-analysis, mediation

Suppose that I am looking at data from an N = 32, within-subjects study.

There are three IVs - **CL, PL, CPL** - with two ordinal levels each (**0** and **1**). Every subject undergoes each of the 8 configurations of IVs exactly once.

During each configuration of **(CL, PL, CPL)**, two dependent variables, **A** and **Z**, are measured four times each. **A** is a four-level nominal categorical variable with possible values **0, 1, 2,** and **3**, whereas **Z** is a continuous bounded variable. **A** and **Z** are always measured at the same time, hence there is one measurement of **Z** corresponding to each measurement of **A**. This yields, at the conclusion of data collection, 32 measurements of **A** and 32 measurements of **Z** for each of the 32 subjects.

---

Suppose that after collecting the data, it is observed that the fourth level of **A** is particular rare across the subjects. That is, for many of the subjects, when examining the measurements of **A** across a particular configuration of the two of the IVs, or even just a particular level of one IV, there are no measurements of the fourth level to be found.

For example, for a particular subject, across all **(CL, PL, CPL)** such that **CL = 0** and **PL = 0**, the observed measurements of **A** in no particular order are: **[0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1]**, omitting the fourth level, **3**. For another subject, across all **(CL, PL, CPL)** such that **CL = 1**, **3** is not be found among the 16 measurements of **A**.

Such scarcity is present across most of the subjects, and across many of the configurations for a given subject.

---

Taking into account the extensive scarcity of values among the measurements of A and the fact that A is a four-level categorical variable that is measured rather than fixed, what would be the most appropriate way to answer the following questions about data?

**(1)**. Whether **CL, PL, CPL** individually and/or interactively (including **CL, PL, CPL, CLxPL, CLxCPL, PLxCPL)** exert a significant effect on the measurements of (four-level categorical) **A**.

**(2)**. Whether **CL, PL, CPL** individually and/or interactively exert a significant effect on the measurements of (continuous, bounded) **Z**. [Would a repeated measures ANOVA be appropriate?]

**(3)**. Whether the measurements of **A** are significantly predictive of, or correlated with (which is more statistically valid?) the measurements of **Z**.

**(4)**. Whether, and the extent to which if so, the measurements of **A** *mediate* the effects of **CL, PL, CPL** (individually and/or interactively) on the measurements of **Z**, taking into account the results of **(1)**.

**(5)**. Whether **CL, PL, CPL** individually and/or interactively exert a significant effect on the extent to which **(3)** is true.

**(6)**. I am also aware that in order to answer these questions, I must restructure the data to treat **A** as a sort of predictor variable, but am not sure how to deal with the missing data and the fact that there are sometimes two or three measurements of a given value of **A** within a particular configuration of conditions. In the latter case, would I go about averaging the values of **Z** across those two or three measurements?

---

Please let me know if there is anything I've explained unclearly or if any other edits should be made. Thank you for your help and efforts!